# How to connect elastic docker agent correctly in a docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I have setup a docker-compose file which has 3 containers:

- elasticsearch
- kibana
- elastic docker agent

I want the elastic docker agent to send logs from other containers to elasticsearch and then I should be able to see those logs in kibana. I followed the examples in the official documentation and managed to setup the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=my-cluster
      - node.name=elasticsearch-01
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      elastic-stack:


  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.3
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - SERVER_NAME=kibana.example.com
      - SERVER_HOST="0.0.0.0"
      - "XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false"
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      elastic-stack:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elastic-agent:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/elastic-agent:7.16.3
    container_name: elastic-agent
    volumes:
      - ./elastic-agent.yml:/usr/share/elastic-agent/elastic-agent.yml
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
    restart: always
    networks:
      - elastic-stack

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic-stack:
    driver: bridge
```

The containers are starting successfully but no data is being sent to elastisearch. I see the following messages in the container terminal of the elastic docker agent:

```
    2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.699Z    INFO    application/application.go:67   Detecting execution mode
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.700Z    INFO    application/application.go:76   Agent is managed locally
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.700Z    INFO    capabilities/capabilities.go:59 capabilities file not found in /usr/share/elastic-agent/state/capabilities.yml
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.939Z    INFO    [composable.providers.docker]   docker/docker.go:43     Docker provider skipped, unable to connect: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.939Z    INFO    [api]   api/server.go:62        Starting stats endpoint
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.939Z    INFO    application/local_mode.go:168   Agent is starting
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.940Z    INFO    [api]   api/server.go:64        Metrics endpoint listening on: /usr/share/elastic-agent/state/data/tmp/elastic-agent.sock (configured: unix:///usr/share/elastic-agent/state/data/tmp/elastic-agent.sock)
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.940Z    INFO    application/local_mode.go:178   Agent is stopped
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.941Z    INFO    application/periodic.go:79      Configuration changes detected
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.942Z    INFO    application/periodic.go:101     No configuration change
2023-03-14 11:20:50 2023-03-14T10:20:50.942Z    INFO    application/periodic.go:101     No configuration change
```

This message in particular is interesting since it shows that connection with docker is not successful:

```
2023-03-14 11:20:40 2023-03-14T10:20:40.939Z    INFO    [composable.providers.docker]   docker/docker.go:43     Docker provider skipped, unable to connect: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Also, last but not least, here is my elastic agent configuration:

```
outputs:
  elasticsearch:
    type: elasticsearch
    hosts: ["http://elasticsearch:9200"] 
    index: "elastic-agent-logs-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```